# Question regarding the scope of my global variable {matlab}

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

[image: Gui]
i'm trying to do an assignment for my class and the undo button click should reload the previous transformation applied onto the image in case i wish to go back.
The golabal variable is defined in the start of the code [image]

```
function LoadimgBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to LoadimgBtn (see GCBO)
[filename,pathname]=uigetfile('C:\Users\hassan\Desktop\DIP PROJECT IMGS\MonoChrome 
Images\*.jpg;*.png;*.jpeg');
file_path=strcat(pathname,filename);
og_img=imread(file_path);
axes(handles.org_img);
imshow(og_img);
prev_img=og_img;
axes(handles.intr_img);
imshow(prev_img);
```

As observed the global variable prev_img is utlized perfectly here however when i try to use the same variable in my undo code there is an error thrown that the variable does not exist.

```
function UndoBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

axes(handles.intr_img);

imshow(prev_img);
```

[image: Error]

I wish to utilize the same variable through the global variable method.

Comment: I don't see a `global prev_img` anywhere in your code.

Comment: it has been initialized right after the initialization codes that the gui creates on it self.
Please refer to the second image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call the global variable again in your function code

```
function UndoBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

axes(handles.intr_img);
global prev_img % declaring a global variable "again"
imshow(prev_img);
```

Otherwise, you are overshadowing the global varibale with a local variable of the same name. (remember that you can also define function with the same name as a matlab function e.g. `sum`.) The thing is, that matlab does not know, that you want the variable to be global. The same is true for persistent variables.
Once you define a global variable in your function, matlab checks if this (global) variable already exists and if it has already a value.
You may want to have a look in the [matlab-docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) if my explanation wasn't intuitive enough.

To clear a global variable, you need to call `clearvars -global` or `clear all` or `clear global`

> - To clear a global variable from all workspaces, use clear global    variable.
> - To clear a global variable from the current workspace but    not    other workspaces, use clear variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in mat lab every time you use a global variable you have to re declare it within the scope of a function as well.
I am not sure however I think it creates a local instance of the variable with the same name if i do no explicitly mention the keyword global within the scope of the function as i was doing so before.

in my case i had to mention global at two locations and it works.
[image: gloabl mention 1]
[image]

Comment: **Post code as text**! Pictures are harder to read, can't be copied, are less accessibility friendly, and besides everything else it's just easier to copy code you already have as text than to save and upload screenshots! From your question you've shown you already know how to format code...